# Generate all possible polynomial combinations

Tags: python, ruby

How can i generate all possible polynomials for coefficients of 1..10 and a degree of 10 ?
preferably in Python or ruby .

I have found [PythonPoly](http://code.google.com/p/python-poly/) module , but still dont understand how to make it .

Thanks .

Comment: How many (and what) variables? Which coefficient goes with which degree? What do you mean by "polynomial combinations"? Do you mean polynomials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want somebody to do your homework for you . 
But here you go ...

`my_polynomials = itertools.product(range(1, 11), repeat=10)`

Then :

```
for p in my_polynomials:
    do_something_with_polynomial(p)
```

Comment: Use the `repeat` keyword argument: `product(range(1, 11), repeat=10)`.

Comment: this command returns <itertools.product object at 0x2762e60> .

Answer (score 1):

This is a Ruby versioin

```
my_polynomials = (1..10).to_a.repeated_combination(10)
```

To print the first 50:

```
my_polynomials.take(50).each{|mp| p mp}
```